# “Ich gehe oft ins Kino aus.” – Where to best place “abends”?

Tags: word-order, time, separable-verb

I want to answer the question “Gehen Sie abends oft aus?” saying that I go to the movies (“ins Kino”).

Which of the following would I say?

> Abends gehe ich oft ins Kino aus.
>
> Ich gehe abends oft ins Kino aus.

The second one feels more natural to me.

Answer (score 3):

Both variants are indeed correct, with regard to the `word order`, **but**, as [M. Zuberbühler](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26968/9028) said, the ***aus*** is unnecessary, and the sentences are both in fact grammatically incorrect if you keep it, and here's why:

Most likely you're thinking of the way answering is done in English by repeating as much of the question in your answer as possible. (Which I was taught in school showed politeness, *shrug*; something I feel is unnecessary in German (by which I mean the repetition, of course; politeness is always necessary in conversation). I would be perfectly alright with "Ja, ins Kino" as an answer if I asked you: "Gehen Sie abends oft aus?" - as the asker I know what I asked you, I wouldn't need you to repeat my own question back to me. But that is just my personal preference, and anyway I'm degressing.)

You should however not repeat *ausgehen* in your answer, nor would you do so in English:

> Q: Are you *going **out*** tonight?
>
> A: Yes, I'm *going **to the cinema*** tonight.

It's the exact same thing in German. Since you're specifying a place you're going to -- the cinema -- you don't need the generic **out** anymore, in fact it feels wrong to keep it. "Yes, I'm going out to the cinema tonight.", sounds wrong in English as well (to me at least, but I'm no native speaker).

So the use of ***aus**gehen* is correct if it is the translation of a generic *going **out***, but use *ins (=in das) Kino, Theater, Cafe, Restaurant / in die Stadt, Schule, Disco gehen* if you specify a place or places you're going to, leaving out the "***aus***", as you would leave out the ***out*** in English.

Comment: Welcome to German language. May i suggest you edit your answer a bit? In fact, *Ich gehe heute Abend ins Kino aus* is not correct german. It would either be *ich gehe (...)* aus* OR *ich gehe (...) ins Kino*, but you cannot combine them.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, but you can take the "aus" away. It sounds better without it.

Comment: I think it is not a question of "can" but "should". With "aus" is sounds strange!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with him. You can also say It like this

Am Abend gehe ich oft ins Kino (aus).

Comment: Who do you agree with?

Comment: I strongly disagree. Only without the *aus* are those suggestions correct (or without the specification where the speaker is going, but not both).